# How do I not match a word in a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

If it possible to write a regex that matches `bundle-` followed by anything except when anything is `map`, so:

```
bundle-hello = match
bundle-map = don't match
bundle-ma = match
bundle- = match
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?!...)`) which will make sure `bundle-` is not followed by `map`:

```
bundle-(?!map)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/nK2uB9)

---

**Javascript:**

```
var RegExp = /bundle-(?!map)/;

RegExp.test('bundle-hello'); // true
RegExp.test('bundle-map');   // false
```